# Allow access to iPhone contact for my app in iOS 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, abaddressbook, abaddressbooksource

In my application I am accessing phone contact of iPhone so it will ask first time to allow access,but if user will click on "Don't allow" than application will not be able to access phone contact.

I know that in iOS 6.0 there is a option of privacy in setting where I can give permission to access phone contact to my application.

But I couldn't find this kind of tab or setting in iOS 5 or lower,Please inform me where can I give permission to my application to access phone contacts.
-Thanks in advance

Comment: i know about that but if user click on don't allow than how can he give that permission from setting ,is there any option available for that?

Comment: +1,Have you found any solution ? looking for the same. Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this permission level is introduced in ios6. This one you can't find iOS5. And in iOS6 if user gave Don't Allow at first time, you can change that settings from the Settings App in the iOS.

**Privacy Settings**
To find your privacy settings, just tap the Settings app to launch it and then scroll down to Privacy. Tap it.

On the privacy screen, you'll see the elements of your iPhone that contain personal information that apps can gain access to.
(like Location Services,Contacts,Calendars and Reminders,Photos). From here you can change the access level.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the anmswer Mathew,but I know about that but I am asking for the iOS 5.0 is it possible to change access for iOS 5.0???

Comment: You don't need permission for accessing the contacts from the phone in iOS5. Therefore you can't set as well. :-)

Comment: Yea. iOS5 and below will demand Permission for Location Services but not for contacts. But in iOS6 we need permission from user to access the contact list as well as the location services and a lot more. See More @ http://www.macrumors.com/2012/06/14/apple-requires-user-permission-before-apps-can-access-personal-data-in-ios-6/